# How Can I simulate a driverless Car using ROS and gazebo

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I completely new to ROS and Gazebo and now I was asked by my professor to use these two programs to simulate a car that will avoid obstacles and lane shift from the left most lane to the right most lane on a high way automatically without a driver but i don't know how to start although i finished most of the ROS and gazebo packages

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258589/how-can-i-simulate-a-driverless-car-using-ros-and-gazebo/) by [BishoyGeorgeWadie13](https://answers.ros.org/users/29933/bishoygeorgewadie13/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-04-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

https://github.com/osrf/car_demo as @kentam said could be what you want.

https://github.com/CPFL/Autoware also might be helpful.

---

Originally posted by [vkee](https://answers.ros.org/users/21470/vkee/) with karma: 127 on 2017-08-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

FYI

http://www.ros.org/news/2017/06/simulated-car-demo.html

---

Originally posted by [kentam](https://answers.ros.org/users/31544/kentam/) with karma: 11 on 2017-08-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1